# Get ClientIp from Cloudfront in Nginx without using Cloudfront CIDR IPS

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-cloudfront

How to fetch Client-IP from cloudfront in the NODE.JS application, when the AWS EC2 has Nginx server in between?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use CloudFront provided headers, link - [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-cloudfront-headers.html]

1. All you need to do first is Go to Cloudfront -> Select Distribution -> Behaviors -> and do the following in 'Cache key and origin requests'
2. Select '**CachingDisabled**' for 'Cache policy' dropdown, if you don't want anything to get cached. I personally faced problems in my app, if I didn't select this option.
3. For Origin Request Policy do the following -

   Create a new Policy like **'Origin-Policy-For-Cloudfront'** and select **'CloudFront-Viewer-Address'** and checkout other options as well.

   It'll look something like this -

[image]

4. Save it and, finally the Cloudfront Behavior should look like this -

[image]

5. Now, open **conf.d/node.conf** or **nginx.conf**, wherever you have written your 'server -> /location', and simply write the following -

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my-server CLOUDFRONT_URL;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Client-IP $http_CloudFront_Viewer_Address;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         "http://127.0.0.1";
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection $connection_upgrade;
    }
}
```

6. On the NodeJs Backend, you can fetch the Client IP in the request as follows -

   ```
    exports.get = (req, res, next) => {
        console.log('Client IP:', req.headers['x-client-ip']);
    }
   ```

This is an easier method to get the client Ip rather than messing around with Cloudfront CIDR IP ranges and all.